# Wicket Table css not rendered after ajax update?

Tags: java, wicket

I have a datatable with some items. The datatable has some css  on the table tag. When I update the dataproviders model list and send the component back with ajax the css doesn't get rendered.

However if I send the entire page using ajax the table is rendered correct.

Example:

```
<wicket:panel>
  <table class="striped">
  </table>
 </wicket:panel>
```

This css class gives odd and even a different css.

This is how I update the component after changing the dataprovider.

```
ajaxRequestTarget.add(MyPage.this.get("myPanel")); //this panel contains the table
```

The data gets added but the css markup is gone.
Refreshing the page brings back the css.

```
ajaxRequestTarget.add(MyPage.this); //send the entire page
```

This works but the entire page gets refreshed(and this make the page scroll up.

Whats the difference in component rendering if you send the entire page, instead of only 1 component/panel?

I'm using chrome.

Comment: Open the page with Chrome (for example) and check the `class` attribute in real time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you render styles via jQuery, you'll have to call it again to re-paint correctly.

```
ajaxRequestTarget.appendJavascript("renderMethod('.striped');");
```

Comment: Oops I misunderstood you're answer. Put you're own method at rendermethod.